# Log on screen issue Windows 7 wireless user after joining new domain

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, login, authentication, radius

In our college domain changed new due to centralized process.
For the security update,
wireless security changed WPA2/Enterprise wireless connection mode.
Now the machines connected through wireless adapter/ laptops.
We created staffs Windows login single wireless sign in mode
[due to the unavailability of LAN cable] and joined new domain.

After restart, we're getting two username & password dialog boxes
for log on screen.
How I can avoid "Windows will try to connect to [Wi-Fi SSID, ... screen shot]
after typing both box its login to Windows otherwise getting error.

After login Windows again need to sign in addition log on for wireless connectivity so how I can bypass this issue?
I need auto configuration and normal login window.

Any help?

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured your RADIUS server and have you configured Windows 7 to use your Windows username and password to log in to your WPA2 Enterprise wifi? This may be why you get the doubled-up login screen.

Comment: yes radius server already configured

Comment: i have found temporary solution may some of guys helps it future. just remove validate certificate, also join those system one time through lan cable.